# Dolphin Android Studio created problem on importing Project in Kotlin with an exception Error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I got the following errors when importing the project on Dolphin Android Studio. I could not figure ,how to solve this?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://maven .google.com
Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://maven .google.com

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://maven .google.com
Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://maven .google.com
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at 



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely: `https://maven .google.com` there is a whitespace between `maven` and the `.`

Also if you read the error message carefully, it tells you where exactly the issue is: `Illegal character [..] at index 8`